# How to get the value from MySQL from table field like 'Feildname-1'?

Tags: mysql

Hai I am having the table `USERS` with the fields like

`USERACCNO`
`FIELD-1` 
`FIELD-2`
.
.
.
.
.
.
`FIELD-10`

Now I want to get the Value from field-2 .SO I wrote a query like this 
`SELECT FEILD-2 FROM USERS WHERE USERACCNO='1'`
 But It returns `error`.
So I wrote a query Like this `SELECT 'FEILD-2' FROM USERS WHERE USERACCNO='1'`
Here I got the `result 'FEILD-2' instead of field-2 value`.How can I get the result for field-2 value?What's the wrong with my query or table structure?Thanks in advance.

Updated:
FEILD-2  to FIELD-2 
FEILD-10  to FIELD-10

Comment: Is there a reason that field is misspelled in the second one?

Comment: OOPs...No.. Its just my mistake..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use backticks in MySQL for identifiers that contain special characters (such as the dash sign):

```
SELECT `FIELD-2` FROM users WHERE useraccno = '1';
```